# What is the most efficient way to handle a duplicate record in a linked list?

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, linked-list

I am implementing an ordered linked list, and I would like to know what is the most efficient way to handle a duplicate record when I call the insert method. Is it better to search if the record already exists before the operation or to assess whether the record already exists within the operation and to throw an exception?

**Method #1**

```
public void insert(int key){
    if(isEmpty())
        head = new Node(key);
    else if(key < head.data){
        /* Code to verify if they are equal */
        /* ... */
        /* ... */
        Node new_node = new Node(key);
        new_node.next = head;
        head = new_node;
    }else{
        Node tmp = head;
        while((head.nex != null) && (key > tmp.key)){
            /* Code to verify if they are equal */
            /* ... */
            /* ... */
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        /* Create node and change "pointers"*/
        /* ... */
        /* ... */
    }               
}
```

**Method #2**

```
public void insert(int key){
    if(exists(key)){
        /* Throw an exception */
    }
    /* Code for insert element */
    /* ... */
    /* ... */       
}
```

Comment: It's obviously more efficient to check within the same iteration.

Comment: If efficiency is the goal, why use a linked list?

Comment: Linked list API generally allow duplicate entries. Lists also make some promises about their performance. For example, inserting a value into a list should take constant time, checking for duplicate entries will increase that to O(n). If you must guarantee that the entries are unique you may be thinking of a different data structure such as set.

Comment: @LeffeBrune Thank you for responding and for the suggestion, it has been useful to me. Actually it is a university assignment. Thanks to the other guys too.

Comment: It's always more efficient to search once rather than twice, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are asking about efficiency it will always be more efficient to perform the check for the duplicates inside of your "insert" implementation. Here is why, assume you have a sorted linked list with N elements. The element you are trying to insert is larger than any of the elements currently in the list. If you search first then insert you would have to traverse N elements to confirm the element is not in the list. You would then traverse the N elements again to find the correct place to insert your new element.

I would suggest writing a "search" method that returns a node with a largest key that is less or equal to the key you are searching for. For example given a list `{ 1, 2, 5, 7, 10 }` and a search key `6`, your search method should return the node `5`. You can now call search inside of your insert method, and if it will return either a node with the key you searched for, or a node with a largest key still smaller than your search key after which you can insert a new node with the search key value. Something like this:

```
insert(k)
  Node n = search(k) // what should search return if the list is empty?
  if (n.data < k)
     // insert new node after "n"
  else
     // handle existing key
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation dude , now it's clearer to me.

Comment: One suggestion: Instead of searching and then again traversing the list to insert the element, you can search and insert in one go in a sorted list. For Example [1, 3, 5, 7, 10] and the key is 8. When you reach the last node, you know that 10 is larger than given key i.e., 8. So insert before the element 10.

Comment: @NaghaveerGowda that why I suggested having a search method that returns a position in the list for insertion even if the element not found.

Comment: @LeffeBrune Here you are traversing the list twice. One, you are searching for the position to insert and another traversal to insert the element. Why can't you do both in one traversal?

Comment: @NaghaveerGowda no I am not, I call search inside of insert method. "search" returns a node which I can update to insert the element right after it.